# Create an API in C# which can be called from it's DLL

Tags: c#, api, dll

I know the title is bit confusing for my question.

Let me explain:-
There are some DLLs written by my seniors and I use them in C# as follows:

Say, Existing DLL name is SeniorDLL and I want to use function SeniorFunc from that DLL.
What I do is:-

```
private delegate int SeniorFunc(IntPtr Blah);

[DllImport("kernel32")]
public extern static IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public extern static IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);

SeniorFunc fp_Senior;
```

and in function where I want to use this function, Before first function call I write:

IntPtr handle;

```
    handle = IntPtr.Zero;
    handle = LoadLibrary("<DLL Path>");

    IntPtr fPtr = GetProcAddress(handle, "SeniorFunc");
    fp_Senior = (SeniorFunc)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fPtr, typeof(SeniorFunc));
```

and then I use this function via `fp_Senior(<Parameter>);`

Now I want to create such DLL for me in C# by which I'll be able to call functions from DLL.
Currently I created a DLL but I have create an instance of class in DLL and then have to access like `ClassInstance.MyFunction(<Parameters>)`;

How can I get directly function calls without creating an instance?
In other words, (I don't know I am correct or wrong) How can I create APIs??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a thing as a method outside a class in C#. So if you must call a method, you have to specify the class name.

The difference with the DLLs you are currently using is that those DLLs are written in C/C++ or other non-.NET language which does not enforce a strict object-oriented approach like C# does.

Thus, nothing forces you to create an instance of a class when calling a method from a .NET library. If a method is declared as `static`, you can call it directly through `ClassName.MethodName()`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an instance here, everything can be static.  Something like this, with the necessary error checking added:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

internal static class NativeMethods {
    public static void SeniorFunc(IntPtr arg) {
        if (fp_Senior == null) lookUpSenior();
        fp_Senior(arg);
    }

    private static void lookUpSenior() {
        loadSenior();
        IntPtr addr = GetProcAddress(SeniorModule, "seniorfunc");
        if (addr == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();
        fp_Senior = (SeniorFuncDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(addr, typeof(SeniorFuncDelegate));
    }
    private static void loadSenior() {
        if (SeniorModule == IntPtr.Zero) {
            SeniorModule = LoadLibrary("mumble.dll");
            if (SeniorModule == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }
    private static IntPtr SeniorModule;

    private delegate int SeniorFuncDelegate(IntPtr Blah);
    private static SeniorFuncDelegate fp_Senior;

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private extern static IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
    public extern static IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string lpProcName);

}
```

The point of keeping lookupSenior in a separate method is to allow SeniorFunc() to get inlined so it is fast.  If you know you'll *always* use these functions in your program then you can also write a static constructor for the class and do the lookup there.  Saves the null check but makes an exception a bit harder to interpret.